# Define List that Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of time records that have 1 digit, 1 decimal, 2 digits, and an "hrs" description.

I'm looking to only get the first 4 characters of my list. But my list isn't constant so I can't write a VBA code to backspace records from A2:A100 (example range).

I need help defining my list (because the range of records changes) and then keystroking three backspaces for every value in my list. The reason I use three backspaces is because I can use a color scale on my new list that is now stored as a Number.

Below is a snippet of what I'm working with:

```
Original List          New List (I will use a color scale)
1.96 hrs               1.96
1.73 hrs               1.73
0.00 hrs               0.00
1.90 hrs               1.90
```

I will also consider simply being able to use a color scale on my original list. My only guess in achieving this would be to format the values on my original list as Numbers. However, I've tried changing the formatting but I still can't use a color scale.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just do a find/replace for the `hrs`

Comment: Use the subsitute function or the Text to Columns wizard.

Comment: Wow, I think this might have been the easiest solution! I don't have to define my list of values either. I can do the find/replace for `hrs` and then just color code what I need!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need VBA.  You can just use built-in formulas.

First four characters, converted to value:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2, 4))
```

Replace " hrs", convert to value:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, " hrs"))
```

There are lots of other ways to do it.

Comment: I just tried this, I am able to return a value but the reason I wanted VBA is so that I can use an autocomplete for all the values in my list. I can't use autocomplete with this formula.

Comment: @Computer_Nerd, I don't know what you mean by that, and your original question mentions nothing about an auto-complete capability, nor any other reason why VBA would be a requirement.